# SQL function to return two values and assign to two variable in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to get back two values from the the function and first value assign to one variable and second value assign to another variable write now i get by calling the function two time by passing return type parameter for example @retType 1 then return first value if @retType 2 then return second value
but i need to call fuinction two time but my intension is to call only one time and get two values to two variable is it possible ?...

Stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @policy_effitive_st DATE  -- policy Period Start From
DECLARE @policy_effitive_end DATE -- calculated date  

SELECT
    @policy_effitive_end = policydatecalc(memberid)  --assign first column column1
    , @policy_effitive_end = policydatecalc(memberid) --assign second column column2
FROM
    member
```

Function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [owner].[policydatecalc]
     (@parm1 <datatpe> = <default>)
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN
  (
   DECLARE  @col1,@col2 date 
   --- calulation for dates logic here
  SELECT @col1,@col2   )
```

Comment: people are downvoting instead of giving reference or answear becasue downvoting is free

Comment: Sorry - your question just isn't clear - makes no sense.... how are this function and the stored procedure related? I don't see that one is calling the other or anything....

Comment: this just an example i wnat to implement  store procedure caliing function like these dbo.policydatecalc(memberid)

Comment: A stored procedure can use [output parameters](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187004%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to return more than one value. Aside: Like it or not, StackOverflow is an English language website. The spelling, punctuation, capitalization and grammar errors in your question may be causing downvoting as "unclear".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a table-valued function like this (see the details of exactly **how** to define a table-valued function in the [official MSDN or Technet documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - they are really good and extensive!):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.policydatecalc
     (@NumberOfMonths INT = 1)
RETURNS @OutputTbl TABLE (DateValStart DATE, DateValEnd DATE)
AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @OutputTbl (DateValStart, DateValEnd)
    VALUES (SYSDATETIME(), DATEADD(MONTH, @NumberOfMonths, SYSDATETIME()));

    RETURN
END
```

and then you can call it and assign its values in the stored procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SomeProcedure
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Start DATE, @End DATE

    SELECT
        @Start = DateValStart,
        @End = DateValEnd
    FROM
        dbo.policydatecalc(4)
END
```

The function declaration defines a **table type** (and a variable of that type) that gets returned - and that's what you'll get back in the stored procedure when you call the function. This is like any other table - you can select from it and assign the values to internal variables in the stored procedure.